# Rails generate controller command not building view files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

I have been struggling to understand why I can't get view files created for my Rails project. The documentation shows that generating a controller also generates an associated view:
[Rails Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFxYl.png)

If I use that same command, I get one file generated, being the controller.
[My command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxaoW.png)

The only two files within the Views folder in my Rails project are mailer.html.erb and mailer.text.erb

Am I doing something wrong? Do I manually create the view files, and if so I can't seem to get them "connected" to the associated controller. I am new to Rails, so any insight would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this command :

```
rails g controller Articles index create
```

You can create methods and views dynamically after If you typed controller name in command.

Comment: What is the 'create' word doing in this command?

Comment: similar with index. If you typed the code, you created index and create method in Articles controller. After that Rails create articles/index.html.erb and create.html.erb in views directory.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating only a controller in your command not any methods that's why the views are not generated. If you need to generate views for the particular methods then you may run the below listed command.

> rails g controller Articles index show

Here, index, show are the methods name. So, this command will create ArticlesController and also the respective view files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [scaffold](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding) option.

```
rails g scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text
```

This command will generate the following files.

| File | Purpose |
| --- | --- |
| `db/migrate/20100207214725_create_posts.rb` | Migration to create the posts table in your database (your name will include a different timestamp) |
| `app/models/post.rb` | The Post model |
| `test/unit/post_test.rb` | Unit testing harness for the posts model |
| `test/fixtures/posts.yml` | Sample posts for use in testing |
| `config/routes.rb` | Edited to include routing information for posts |
| `app/controllers/posts_controller.rb` | The Posts controller |
| `app/views/posts/index.html.erb` | A view to display an index of all posts |
| `app/views/posts/edit.html.erb` | A view to edit an existing post |
| `app/views/posts/show.html.erb` | A view to display a single post |
| `app/views/posts/new.html.erb` | A view to create a new post |
| `app/views/posts/_form.html.erb` | A partial to control the overall look and feel of the form used in edit and new views |
| `test/functional/posts_controller_test.rb` | Functional testing harness for the posts controller |
| `app/helpers/posts_helper.rb` | Helper functions to be used from the post views |
| `test/unit/helpers/posts_helper_test.rb` | Unit testing harness for the posts helper |
| `app/assets/javascripts/posts.js.coffee` | CoffeeScript for the posts controller |
| `app/assets/stylesheets/posts.css.scss` | Cascading style sheet for the posts controller |
| `app/assets/stylesheets/scaffolds.css.scss` | Cascading style sheet to make the scaffolded views look better |